# Interoperability between javascript's elliptic library and golang's ecdsa library

Tags: javascript, typescript, go, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am experiencing difficulty validating a signature generated with the elliptic javascript library using the ecdsa library from golang.The elliptic curve being used is the secp256k1.

Here are some code snippets:

Typescript utility functions:

```
import * as bigInt from 'big-integer';
declare const require: any;
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");


const generatePrivateKey = function(): string {
    return ec.genKeyPair().getPrivate().toString();
}

const generatePublicKey = function(privateKey: string): PublicKey {
    const publicKey: any = ec.keyFromPrivate(privateKey).getPublic();
    return new PublicKey(
        publicKey.getX().toString("hex"),
        publicKey.getY().toString("hex")
    );
}

const signMessage = function(message: string, privateKey: string): Signature {
    message = SHA256(message).toString();
    const key = ec.keyFromPrivate(privateKey);
    const signature: Signature = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(key.sign(message)));
    return new Signature(signature.r, signature.s, signature.recoveryParam);
}

const verifyMessage = function(message: string, publicKey: PublicKey, signature: Signature): boolean {
    message = SHA256(message).toString();
    const key = ec.keyFromPublic(publicKey, 'hex');
    return key.verify(message, signature);
}

class PublicKey {
    constructor(
        public x: string,
        public y: string
    ) { }
}

class Signature {
    constructor(
        public r: string,
        public s: string,
        public recoveryParam: number
    ) { }
}
```

Sample signature generated using function above:

```
// Private Key
const privateKey = "87447468790127269743127941512029311682561810964950681691418579250915022213638"

// Public Key
const publicKey = {
  x: 'fe0f1982436d08bfc2a603d85738bc874cbc4d2108e63eca0264afd8e62244df',
  y: '199b6155f2532aa5d6404c32ea5fb7de1c9af741b99d75dcb73285bfd8525176'
}

// Sample message
const message = "hello world"

// Generated Signature
const signature = {
  r: 'be4022f929aa1aef40e563a0e30e1b23b9ca5a73d510cf9d95a2a51db4f52965',
  s: 'c27b747099192bda25985fdd5dd588de44c40b15aa038aa65399aa5e9e5ec7b',
  recoveryParam: 1
}
```

Go code used to verify signature:

```
xVal := new(big.Int)
xVal.SetString("fe0f1982436d08bfc2a603d85738bc874cbc4d2108e63eca0264afd8e62244df", 16)
yVal := new(big.Int)
yVal.SetString("199b6155f2532aa5d6404c32ea5fb7de1c9af741b99d75dcb73285bfd8525176", 16)

rVal := new(big.Int)
rVal.SetString("be4022f929aa1aef40e563a0e30e1b23b9ca5a73d510cf9d95a2a51db4f52965", 16)
sVal := new(big.Int)
sVal.SetString("c27b747099192bda25985fdd5dd588de44c40b15aa038aa65399aa5e9e5ec7b", 16)


hash := fmt.Sprintf(
    "%x",
    sha256.Sum256([]byte("hello world")),
)

pubKey := ecdsa.PublicKey{
    Curve: secp256k1.S256(),
    X:     xVal,
    Y:     yVal,
}

fmt.Printf("SIG VERIFICATION: %v", ecdsa.Verify(&pubKey, []byte(hash), rVal, sVal))
```

The output is:

```
SIG VERIFICATION: false
```

The output should be true. If there are any questions on further details please notify me.

[Javascript Elliptic Library](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic)

[Golang edcsa library](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/)

Comment: The key pair was generated using the elliptic js library. According to the library the key pair is valid

Comment: try to decode your hex string in go using `hex.DecodeString(hash)` instead of `[]byte(...;`

Comment: @Topaco Source code has been updated. For any further specifics you may refer to the library's source code at https://github.com/indutny/elliptic

Comment: @mh-cbon You are a genius, Problem solved. This example will be handy for individuals using a go back-end and a mobile or web front-end. Thanks a million.

Comment: noted. @mh-cbon any idea on the reverse? It's not as straightforward as it might seem

Comment: can you make new thread please with the relevant code ?

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983356/verifying-signature-generated-from-golang-ecdsa-library-using-javascripts-ellip

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to hash the message hash using the DecodeString function. Below is the updated code for the solution:

```
xVal := new(big.Int)
xVal.SetString("fe0f1982436d08bfc2a603d85738bc874cbc4d2108e63eca0264afd8e62244df", 16)
yVal := new(big.Int)
yVal.SetString("199b6155f2532aa5d6404c32ea5fb7de1c9af741b99d75dcb73285bfd8525176", 16)

rVal := new(big.Int)
rVal.SetString("be4022f929aa1aef40e563a0e30e1b23b9ca5a73d510cf9d95a2a51db4f52965", 16)
sVal := new(big.Int)
sVal.SetString("c27b747099192bda25985fdd5dd588de44c40b15aa038aa65399aa5e9e5ec7b", 16)

msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
    "%x",
    sha256.Sum256([]byte("hello world")),
)
    
pubKey := ecdsa.PublicKey{
    Curve: secp256k1.S256(),
    X:     xVal,
    Y:     yVal,
}

hash, hashDecodeError := hex.DecodeString(msgHash)

if hashDecodeError != nil {
    log.Println(hashDecodeError)
    panic("internal server error")
}

fmt.Printf("SIG VERIFICATION: %v", ecdsa.Verify(&pubKey, hash, rVal, sVal))
```

The verification using the code above will evaluate to true.

Credits to user [mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) for the solution.