# Verifying signature generated from golang ecdsa library using javascript's elliptic library

Tags: javascript, typescript, go, cryptography, elliptic-curve

This thread is a continuation of an older thread found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975929/interoperability-between-javascripts-elliptic-library-and-golangs-ecdsa-librar?noredirect=1#comment113140122_63975929)

In the previous thread the objective of successfully verifying a signature generated from javascript's elliptic library was successfully accomplished using golang's elliptic library. The question of this thread is how can the reverse be achieved? That is successfully verifying a valid digital signature generated using golang in javascript. The elliptic curve being used is the secp256k1.

Golang utility functions:

```
package utils

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/secp256k1"
)

//GeneratePrivateKey : ecdsa.PrivateKey
func GeneratePrivateKey() (*big.Int, error) {
    var privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey
    var privateKeyGenerationError error
    privateKey, privateKeyGenerationError = ecdsa.GenerateKey(secp256k1.S256(), rand.Reader)
    if privateKeyGenerationError != nil {
        return privateKey.D, privateKeyGenerationError
    }
    return privateKey.D, nil
}

//GeneratePublicKey :
func GeneratePublicKey(privateKey *big.Int) ecdsa.PublicKey {
    var pri ecdsa.PrivateKey
    pri.D, _ = new(big.Int).SetString(fmt.Sprintf("%x", privateKey), 16)
    pri.PublicKey.Curve = secp256k1.S256()
    pri.PublicKey.X, pri.PublicKey.Y = pri.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarBaseMult(pri.D.Bytes())

    publicKey := ecdsa.PublicKey{
        Curve: secp256k1.S256(),
        X:     pri.PublicKey.X,
        Y:     pri.PublicKey.Y,
    }

    return publicKey
}

//Signature :
type Signature struct {
    R *big.Int
    S *big.Int
}

//SignMessage : Generates a valid digital signature for golang's ecdsa library
func SignMessage(message string, privateKey *big.Int) (Signature, error) {
    var result Signature
    msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%x",
        sha256.Sum256([]byte(message)),
    )
    privateKeyStruct, privateKeyGenerationError := ecdsa.GenerateKey(secp256k1.S256(), rand.Reader)
    if privateKeyGenerationError != nil {
        return result, privateKeyGenerationError
    }

    privateKeyStruct.D = privateKey

    signatureR, signatureS, signatureGenerationError := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, privateKeyStruct, []byte(msgHash))
    if signatureGenerationError != nil {
        return result, signatureGenerationError
    }
    result.R = signatureR
    result.S = signatureS
    return result, nil
}

//SignExternalMessage : Generates a valid digital signature for javascript's elliptic library https://github.com/indutny/elliptic
func SignExternalMessage(message string, privateKey *big.Int) (Signature, error) {
    var result Signature
    msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%x",
        sha256.Sum256([]byte(message)),
    )
    privateKeyStruct, privateKeyGenerationError := ecdsa.GenerateKey(secp256k1.S256(), rand.Reader)
    if privateKeyGenerationError != nil {
        return result, privateKeyGenerationError
    }

    privateKeyStruct.D = privateKey
    hash, hashDecodeError := hex.DecodeString(msgHash)

    if hashDecodeError != nil {
        return result, hashDecodeError
    }

    signatureR, signatureS, signatureGenerationError := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, privateKeyStruct, hash)
    if signatureGenerationError != nil {
        return result, signatureGenerationError
    }
    result.R = signatureR
    result.S = signatureS
    return result, nil
}

//VerifyMessage : Verifies signatures generated using golang's ecdsa function
func VerifyMessage(message string, publicKey *ecdsa.PublicKey, signature Signature) (bool, error) {
    msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%x",
        sha256.Sum256([]byte(message)),
    )
    return ecdsa.Verify(publicKey, []byte(msgHash), signature.R, signature.S), nil
}

//VerifyExternalMessage : Verifies signatures generated using the javascript elliptic library
// https://github.com/indutny/elliptic
func VerifyExternalMessage(message string, publicKey *ecdsa.PublicKey, signature Signature) (bool, error) {
    msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%x",
        sha256.Sum256([]byte(message)),
    )
    hash, hashDecodeError := hex.DecodeString(msgHash)

    if hashDecodeError != nil {
        return false, hashDecodeError
    }
    return ecdsa.Verify(publicKey, hash, signature.R, signature.S), nil
}
```

The issue exists in the SignExternalMessage function in code sample above.

The Typescript function responsible for verifying the signature:

```
declare const require: any;
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

public static verifySignature(message: string, publicKey: PublicKey, signature: Signature): boolean {
    message = SHA256(message).toString();
    const key = ec.keyFromPublic(publicKey, 'hex');
    return key.verify(message, signature);
}

class PublicKey {
    constructor(
        public x: string,
        public y: string
    ) { }
}

class Signature {
    constructor(
        public r: string,
        public s: string,
        public recoveryParam: number
    ) { }
}
```

The Typescript code above has no bugs.

Demo code on client (Javascript) using values generated from the golang ecdsa library:

```
// Public key generated using golang
const publicKey = { 
  x:'6847E5B259E624E3A6E04160CAE5837DE19699F4120BFA3E1FA5511B31E014DF',
  y:'1F88E0AFB82D94DB71D99BD749ADE9865BCAE4696EF16709D832C97C4FE4A00F' 
}

const message = "hello world"

// Signature generated using golang
const signature = { 
  r:'9B5D1059C54A60A2C885FD645E07F3066A38E2BB7435B2919877D193AC73F7DB',
  s:'CB819507AE4A88522029C2DCF82290010E340243751FFC8AFE3F12A083713173' 
}

console.log(`SIG VERIFICATION: ${verifySignature(message, publicKey, signature)}`)
```

The code above evaluates to false when it should be true.

If you have any question or suggestions please discourse in the discussion section.

[Javascript Elliptic Library](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic)

[Golang edcsa library](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/)

Comment: your go code is invalid, it does not compile at `signatureR, signatureS, signatureGenerationError := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, privateKeyStruct, []byte(hash))` hash being `[]byte`, you can not write `[]byte(hash)`

Comment: you need not to get the hash as a string, then as a byte array. You can write like this to get a slice of bytes https://play.golang.org/p/_a34GCNNvPe

Comment: please share a full reproducible go code to generate the public key and signatures.

Comment: Golang code has been updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem on my own. The solution was to cast the hash as a byte-array before generating the signature. After doing this the Javascript signature verification evaluated to true. Below is the corrected function:

```
//SignExternalMessage : Generates a valid digital signature for javascript's elliptic library https://github.com/indutny/elliptic
func SignExternalMessage(message string, privateKey *big.Int) (Signature, error) {
    var result Signature
    msgHash := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%x",
        sha256.Sum256([]byte(message)),
    )
    privateKeyStruct, privateKeyGenerationError := ecdsa.GenerateKey(secp256k1.S256(), rand.Reader)
    if privateKeyGenerationError != nil {
        return result, privateKeyGenerationError
    }

    privateKeyStruct.D = privateKey
    hash, hashDecodeError := hex.DecodeString(msgHash)

    if hashDecodeError != nil {
        return result, hashDecodeError
    }

    signatureR, signatureS, signatureGenerationError := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, privateKeyStruct, []byte(hash))
    if signatureGenerationError != nil {
        return result, signatureGenerationError
    }
    result.R = signatureR
    result.S = signatureS
    return result, nil
}
```